# How to set an input field to use 100% of available width in a TD, minus X number of pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a data table which uses 100% of the available browser width. Within some of the TDs there are text input fields. To the right of these are two links, which are used as pickers and styled as block-level elements at 16x16px. The code would look a bit like this:

```
<table (dynamic width)>
  <tr>
    <td (dynamic width)>
      <input type="text" (dynamic width) />
      <a href="#" style="display: block; width 16px; height 16px;"></a>
      <a href="#" style="display: block; width 16px; height 16px;"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like the input field to be use 100% of the available TD width, minus the 32px (16px+16px) of the date pickers. I've tried some techniques referenced in articles on this site but can't seem to find a working solution.

Unfortunately this has to work in IE7+ under an XHTML Strict Doctype.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My guess is you would have to use jQuery/Javascript to locate the element, do some calculations and then set a new width.

Comment: As you're already using tables for layout, you might as well just (ab)use them some more. Just stick another table inside the `td`, containing 3 `td` tags. The first `td` contains the `<input>`, and the last two contain one link each. The last two `td`s should have the width set to `16`, so then the first `td` will take the rest of the space.

Comment: Thirtydot - as mentioned this is mainly a data table so it's not being used for layout purposes. Thankfully left those dark days behind many years ago :)

Answer (score 2):

i know it isnt tagged,

but you might be able to use javascript/jquery to manipulate the DOM elements on your page (which it seems that is what you want to do)

so to manipulate in jquery:

```
$('td input').width($(this).parent().width() - 32)
```

Comment: i said js or jquery. i just supplied the jquery :-p

Comment: My point was it doesnt take much to use pure JS over jQ and you dont get the jQ slowdown and bloat + extra HTTPReq needed to include it.

Comment: @MylesGray but it's one line! _ONE_ line of code. Your's is 3. Think of the bytes your saving. (jQuery is cached on the CDN)

Comment: Pure JS = 41% faster than jQuery solution: http://jsperf.com/jq-vs-js-width-manipulation

Comment: Thanks for the JS/jQuery suggestions guys. Although I was looking for a pure CSS solution I hadn't thought of that approach. The project already uses JS and the Jquery library so that might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You cant do this with pure CSS, but can be done with JS,

A note on the XHTML Strict Doctype - its crap, use Transitional, The XHTML Strict DTD forces you to do stupid stuff like use JS to use `target="_blank"` and other unnecessary not-niceness, I am all in favour of self closing tags as well as quoted parameters but the stuff in XHTML Strict makes me rage.

Okay, moving on.

The Javascript you want is:

```
var input = document.getElementById('blah'),
wrap = document.getElementById('wrap').offsetWidth;
input.style.width = (wrap - 36) + "px";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/My2Qn/

Comment: Yeh, agree on the strict XHTML Doctype. Unfortunately this is for a large website already in existance that I have little control over. Thanks for the JS tips!

Answer (score 0):

Purely using CSS: 
How about using `float:left` for the input type and `float:right` for the date pickers?  Don't forget to use clear:both after the floated elements. Haven't tried it but you can give it a shot.

Comment: Floated elements do not expand to fill their area, so a precise width would have to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

OK - this adds a little extra markup but I think that it does what you want.

### Html

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <div class="holder">
      <input type="text" id="widthInput" />
      <span class="anchors">
      <a href="#" style="display: inline-block; width 16px; height 16px;">a</a>
      <a href="#" style="display: inline-block; width 16px; height 16px;">b</a>
      </span>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
#widthInput{display:inline-block;width:100%;}
div.holder{position:relative;padding-right:32px;}
span.anchors{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;}
```

The `display` for the anchors has been changed to `inline-block` so that the anchors can have a width set and still appear next to each other.

`span.anchors` is a container for the anchors. This has `position:absolute` so that it is removed from the flow of the document and can be positioned where we need it to be.

`div.holder` provides a point of reference for `span.anchors` as it has `position:relative`. If the `td` had `position:relative` then the anchors would be positioned relative to the screen as  is not a block element. The `padding-right` pushes the input away from the right edge so that the anchors display correctly.

Finally, the input is given `width:100%` so that it takes up all of the available space (width of the div less padding). The id is added purely so that the input can be selected through CSS.

I have tested this in FireFox, Chrome and IE and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks, Smirkin - that CSS solution is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

Why all the js for a simple little CSS tweak?

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" style="float: right; width 16px; height 16px;">D2</a>
            <a href="#" style="float: right; width 16px; height 16px;">D1</a>
            <input type="text" style="display:block; margin: 0 32px 0 0;"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you can't change the order of the inputs and links in your HTML, use this instead:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="position:relative;">
            <input type="text" style="display:block; margin: 0 32px 0 0;"/>
            <a href="#" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right:0; width 16px; height 16px;">D2</a>
            <a href="#" style="position: absolute; top:0; right: 16px; width 16px; height 16px;">D1</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```